# Setting individual bits in mongo, to store a bitmask

Tags: mongodb, bit-manipulation

I want to store some flags into a mongo db. For now I have the following:

```
> db.test.save({a:0x1})
> db.test.save({a:0x3})
> db.test.save({a:0x2})
> db.test.save({a:0x2})
> db.test.save({a:0x4})
> db.test.save({a:0x5})
> db.test.find({'$where': "this.a & 0x1"})
```

Is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can do it that way, I'd suggest using separate boolean fields for each flag. That will take up more space but will be faster to query because it won't use javascript and can use indexes if needed. If you need the bitfield for other parts of your application you can keep them both up to date like this (assuming a,b,c... map to bits 0,1,2...):

```
db.c.update({_id:ID}, {$set:{a:true}, $bit:{bits: {or: 0x1}}})
db.c.update({_id:ID}, {$set:{c:false}, $bit:{bits: {and: ~0x8}}})
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of that possibility of course. But is there no way to query like `db.test.find({a:{'$and':0x1}})` or `db.test.find({a: {'$&':0x1}})`?

Comment: No, but we've talked about it. I can't find a jira case, so if you want it I'd suggest opening a ticket at jira.mongodb.org and you will be notified of any changes

Comment: Yes that would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Also querying the bitfield with the modulo operator wouldn't make use of indexes but could regular expressions use a index in any way?

Comment: Regexes can only use indexes for prefix queries. Also I don't think the modulo operator will do what you want, but if it can I'd like to see how.

Comment: What does "prefix queries" mean?

Comment: Modulo: I think `bitfield % (2 ^ field-pos) >= (2 ^ field-pos) / 2` should work to check if a bit at position field-pos from the right is set. To check if a bit is not set, the < operator should fit. But I tested that only very roughly.

Comment: ...seems that the $mod operator can only compare if the modulo result equals to a specific number.

Comment: Okay, I think I got what you mean with "prefix queries": A regular expression like `/^1[01]/` would use the index but `/^[01]1/` not, right?

Answer (score 0):

when your use $where:"this.myField & 0x1" it is same as $where:"0" and $where:"1"
and this is wrong because 0 == false = true, but 0 === false = false

Comment: Hi elser! The question was about _setting_ the bits, not fetching by bits. It happens to everyone, you read the question and answer what you read. Sadly, sometimes we don't see the actual question. I always recommend re-reading both the question and the answer after you've written them. You can always edit your answer later. Good luck!